# How do we implement requirements of password policy?

Tags: 12.04, password, security, authentication, pam

This question might look similar but I could not find a solution to this which covers all the below requirements of the policy, Hence please help me:

```
  - Incorrect pass lockout (after 3 incorrect attempts user shall be locked out for 10 mins)
  - Duration of lockout ( As mentioned in the above point i.e. 10 mins)
  - Minimum length (8)
  - Maximum length (32)
  - Complexity : Minimum 2 small letters
  - Complexity : Minimum 2 Capital letters
  - Complexity : Minimum 2 Numeric digits
  - Complexity : Minimum 2 Special characters
  - Password History ( Must not accept any of the last 10 passwords)
  - No reverse passwords (for ex: if earlier it was TesT@123$ then, it should not take $321@TseT)
  - No incremental passwords (for ex: if earlier it was TesT@123$ then, it should not take TesT@1234$ or TesT@456$ or TesT@234$, etc.. )
  - Must not accept any Dictionary words
```

Thanks in advance!!

**After going through tons of websites I have understood a little about PAM authentication**

[Click here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9648942/) to view my /etc/pam.d/common-password file

Still it is not working giving few errors:

[Click here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9648937/) to see auth logs:

**I have tried heck of combinations but with no success**

can someone help me fix where am I going wrong.

Comment: Password complexity can perhaps be set using [`pam_cracklib`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pam_cracklib.8.html) or [`pam_passwordqc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_passwdqc.8.html), but I don't think you can do extended history without an external authentication service. And lockouts can be set using [`pam_abl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pam_abl.8.html).

Comment: @muru Thanks muru :) Request you to please take a look at the additional info I inserted today in the question and help me fix it. if possible. Thanks in advance!!